# Do I have to secure requests already secured by permissions?

Tags: security, ssh, admin

I have a admin website where every url requires some level of permissions. One of these urls is for deleting user's folder via SSH (different machine). Admin with required rights for this url has also access to all informations about every user (except gdpr restricted). Basically, its kind of superadmin. This admin POSTs username which is part of path used in ssh shell cmd(vulnerability). My colleague recently pointed out that permission is not enough and input should be secured (f.e. regexp) as well even for admin. Is that really necessary? Should we count with scenario where admin (with rights to delete all user's folders) wants to hack virtual machine?